# Poetry: how to define fallback for a specific package

Tags: python, python-poetry

Imagine you develop both a backend and a frontend. When creating the `pyproject.toml` for the frontend, you may like to specify a dependency based on path (and `develop` mode). then when frontend is deployed on your server, that the installation fallback to "official" backend PyPI package.

Something like:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.11"
my-backend = {path = "../my-backend", develop = true}  ## develop mode if available
my-backend = {version = "^3.0.0"}  ## Prod mode fallback since relative path won't exist
```

Is that somehow possible?